# Pivot SQL - Where header includes a DISTINCT and DatePart (data conversion) field

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm trying to adjust the following output to a pivotted table, but I'm struggling and the Distinct and DatePart (data conversions) are impacting it. (I have to use DatePart, datetrunc() isn't available to me).

ORIGINAL

```
SELECT DISTINCT (DatePart(Week, S.Date_)) AS Week, T.NAME,SUM([Call Count]) AS TotalCallCount
FROM Sched S LEFT JOIN
     SchedTy T
     ON S.schedTy_Id = T.id INNER JOIN
     Events a
     ON a.[Event Id] = s.id
WHERE [Call Count] > 0  AND S.Status_id > 0 AND a.DATE BETWEEN '1/1/2019' AND '1/1/2020'
GROUP BY T.Name, DatePart(Week, S.Date_)
```

ORIGINAL OUTPUT

```
Week    EventType   TotalCallCount
1   Public Holiday  6
3   B   1
3   P   3
3   R   9
4   Rec 12
4   R   3
5   P   3
5   R   15
6   Rec 18
7   P   3
7   Rec 6
7   R   12
8   B   1
8   P   6
8   R   18
9   B   1
9   CDM 3
9   P   6
9   R   15
10  OP  3
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (EITHER)

```
    Wk1 Wk2 Wk3 Wk4
Public Holiday              
R               
P               
Rec
```

OR

```
    Public Holiday  R   P   Rec
Wk1             
Wk2             
Wk3             
Wk4
```

I have tried:
Attempt 1
`DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR (MAX) SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ‘,’ + DISTINCT (DatePart(Week, S.Date_))FROM Sched S ORDER By S.Date_ FOR XML PATH(‘’),TYPE).value(‘.’‘NVARCGAR(MAX)’),1,1,’’) Set @query = ‘SELECT T.Name AS EventType,’ + @cols FROM ( SELECT T.Name, S.Date, [Call Count] FROM Sched S LEFT JOIN SchedTy T ON S.schedTy_Id = T.id INNER JOIN Events a   ON a.[Event Id] = s.id WHERE [Call Count] > 0 AND S.Status_id > 0   AND a.DATE BETWEEN '1/1/2019'AND '1/1/2020')  PIVOT(sum([Call Count]) FOR s.Date_ in ('' + @cols + '')) p Execute(@query)`

Attempt 2
`SELECT T.Name, [1] AS Wk1, [2] AS Wk2, [3] AS Wk3, [4] AS Wk4, [5] AS Wk5, [6] AS Wk6, [7] AS Wk7, [8] AS Wk8, [9] AS Wk9, [10] AS Wk10, [11] AS Wk11, [12] AS Wk12, [13] AS Wk13, [14] AS Wk14, [15] AS Wk15, [16] AS Wk16, [17] AS Wk17, [18] AS Wk18, [19] AS Wk19, [20] AS Wk20, [21] AS Wk21, [22] AS Wk22, [23] AS Wk23, [24] AS Wk24, [25] AS Wk25, [26] AS Wk26, [27] AS Wk27, [28] AS Wk28, [29] AS Wk29, [30] AS Wk30, [31] AS Wk31, [32] AS Wk32, [33] AS Wk33, [34] AS Wk34, [35] AS Wk35, [36] AS Wk36, [37] AS Wk37, [38] AS Wk38, [39] AS Wk39, [40] AS Wk40, [41] AS Wk41, [42] AS Wk42, [43] AS Wk43, [44] AS Wk44, [45] AS Wk45, [46] AS Wk46, [47] AS Wk47, [48] AS Wk48, [49] AS Wk49, [10] AS Wk50, [51] AS Wk51, [52] AS Wk52 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (DatePart(Week, S.Date_)) AS Week, T.NAME, ([Call Count]) FROM Sched S LEFT JOIN SchedTy T    ON S.schedTy_Id = T.id INNER JOIN Events a  ON a.[Event Id] = s.id WHERE [Call Count] > 0 AND S.Status_id > 0   AND a.DATE BETWEEN '1/1/2019'       AND '1/1/2020') AS TotalCallCount PIVOT (SUM([Call Count]) FOR(DatePart(Week, S.Date_)) IN [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49], [50], [51], [52])AS pvt`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DatePart(Week, S.Date_) AS Week, T.NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.NAME = 'Public Holiday' THEN [Call Count] END) AS total_public_holiday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.NAME = 'B' THEN [Call Count] END) AS total_b,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.NAME = 'P' THEN [Call Count] END) AS total_p,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.NAME = 'R' THEN [Call Count] END) AS total_r,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.NAME = 'Rec' THEN [Call Count] END) AS total_rec
FROM Sched S LEFT JOIN
     SchedTy T
     ON S.schedTy_Id = T.id INNER JOIN
     Events e
     ON e.[Event Id] = s.id
WHERE [Call Count] > 0  AND
      S.Status_id > 0 AND
      e.DATE >= '2019-01-01' AND
      e.DATE < '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY DatePart(Week, S.Date_)
```